# Bundler downloads gems present on the system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I was wondering, why does bundler always downloads gems that are already present in my gemset? I mean, every time after running `rails new` and `bundle install` commands, bundler is downloading the same gems that are present on the system.Now, I know about `--local` option to prevent this behavior but just thought it would be nice if it could first make a simple check and what is really point of this.

Edit: Sorry guys, it seems that bundler is actually using gems from the system.I thought otherwise because it took him like 20 seconds to finish, but it was due to my very slow internet connection and probably took so much time to resolve dependencies.

Comment: I didn't notice that behaviour of the *bundler*, how do I reproduce that

Comment: Do you mean to say it reinstalls every time you run bundler ? How do you say it is downloading everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler doesn't go re-fetch gems unless one of these things is true:

- You don't have the same gem and the same version (or allowed range of versions) installed.
- You are using RVM and different gemsets for different projects and not placing them inside a global gemset.
- The gem paths are not in the search path Bundler uses.

If this is an issue for you, you can use `--local` as you know to force Bundler never to even look for anything else, but you can also specify the versions for all your gems. And make sure the right version is in *Gemfile.lock*.

In the end, Bundler only does what you tell it to do. Of course, you can also not use Bundler.

Answer (score 0):

The default for `bundle install` is the `--system` option which will install system wide and hence will also use existing gems.

If you are using something like rvm, you will not see this behaviour. Also, note that bundler remembers previous arguments supplied for some paramters like `path`. If it was used before for an application, it will be remembered for future invocations.

`--local` is to use the local cache - http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/bundle-install.1.html